# How to make Motors run for 5 seconds in MicroBit

Tags: bbc-microbit

Im creating a car with the microbit. I have all the components running, and the car built. the rear wheels run of DC circuit motors. How would I code in microbit, to make the power supply or the motor only last 5 seconds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off starting with some of the example projects on the microbit site, because as it stands your question is quite vague. Here is a JavaScript example, assuming you need to drive pin0 to control the motor.

```
function onStart(  ) {
    // Turn the motor on 
    microbit.writePinDigital(0, true);
    // Wait 5 seconds
    wait(5000);
    // Turn the motor off
    microbit.writePinDigital(0, false);
}
```

For this to be really useful, you'll need some sort of control algorithm in order to decide *when* to turn on and off the motors. Have you got a motor driver board? Otherwise, your micro:bit probably won't have enough power to turn the motors (and it might be damaged too). These are details that you should really add to your question - they make it easier for people to write good answers.